# Read dat. file with pandas

Tags: pandas

all, I am trying to laod a dat file into pandas, but failed. I do not know how it should be setted correctly

dat.file like this

```
#S 3398 meshct tripod_z -12.2 -10.8 43 tripod_x -0.42 0.42 12 0.04 False 0.0
#U tangosys
#D Thu Jul 06 14:18:53 2023
#C Acquisition started at Thu Jul  6 14:18:53 2023
#O0 temp_body  temp_resistor  temp_sample  calibid  ceout  calibthreshold  e0  p0
#O1 roihigh  roilow  scalea  shifte  scaleb  clear_bragg  cdmask  cy
#O2 cdx  cdy  cdz  cdxr  caz  cay  caxr  cvg
#O3 cvo  chg  cho  chi  cabd  cabu  dynaV  slit_hgap
#O4 slit_hoffset  slit_voffset  slit_vgap  energy  oh_dcm_pitch  oh_dcm_xtal2_pitch  oh_dcm_xtal2_roll  oh_dcm_exit_offset
#O5 tripod_x  tripod_z  fluo_x  fe_movm_voffset  fe_movm_vgap  fe_movm_hoffset  fe_movm_hgap  oh_vcm_x
#O6 oh_vcm_z  oh_vcm_radius  oh_vcm_pitch  oh_dcm_z  oh_dcm_x  oh_dcm_roll  oh_diag_foil_z  oh_vfm_yaw
#O7 oh_vfm_x  oh_vfm_roll  oh_vfm_radius  oh_vfm_pitch  oh_vfm_stripe  oh_vcm_stripe  oh_filter1  oh_filter2
#O8 oh_filter3  oh_filter4  table_z  oh_dcm_perp  phx  phz
#P0 -290.0 -290.0 -290.0 361986 6466.543887174238 719.694327246 8264.347091 554
#P1 590 330 -0.0679889873766 -0.0307523696346 8302.07520822 66.52760359699293 26.0 179.0
#P2 99.78988561107766 -58.93416974425037 670.244563838333 43.04980905946185 -279.998 567.2513413278066 -47.84396934323133 90.00000097652014
#P3 4.840006020469588 70.00060107043943 -2.129891631547281 1019.3951939519395 2.72368242254423 2.72368242254423 0.0 18.002000000000002
#P4 0.9989999999999988 -3.7689999999999984 16.926000000000002 6553.202591019607 -0.343745546472518 1639.80463980464 -9600.28272727273 25.49990462617748
#P5 0.42020000000000035 -10.695202807127437 0.0 0.5020000000000002 0.9980000000000002 -0.00849999999999973 9.981000000000002 31.54429168302695
#P6 0.35837583399188794 12000.227277031761 3.3503069273596053 7.081767826744996 28.6 2.1834211210108774 16.0075 -0.1097269315603436
#P7 21.49253530251651 1.5417177174197019 6500.00796427756 1.5780083276850208 1 1 0 0
#P8 1 1 36.68902 15.564549999999999 0.22050000000000125 -26.641000000000005
#N 24
#L Pt_No  tripod_z  tripod_x  energyc  a_i0i1_timer  a_i0_1  a_i0_2  a_i1_1  a_i1_2  n_timer  n_i0_1  n_i0_2  n_i1_1  n_i1_2  n_i2_1  n_i2_2  n_icr  n_tcr  n_sca1  n_sca2  n_sca3  n_sca4  sr_i_1  dt
0 -12.2 -0.42 6553.197339281052 0.04 0.5029029846191406 0.5163887023925782 0.007778549194335937 0.012404251098632812 0.04 16831 8019 20 40 15 13 0 0 0 0 0 0 251.6710347854035 0.2
1 -12.167441860465116 -0.42 6553.198955199372 0.04 0.5021286010742188 0.5153976440429687 0.007749176025390625 0.012369155883789062 0.04 16831 8020 20 39 15 12 0 0 0 0 0 0 251.6710347854035 0.24500001065578586
2 -12.134883720930231 -0.42 6553.2013790787205 0.04 0.5018993377685547 0.5150341033935547 0.007617568969726563 0.012250518798828125 0.04 16837 8021 19 39 14 12 0 0 0 0 0 0 251.6710347854035 0.2900000213115717
3 -12.102325581395348 -0.42 6553.2013790787205 0.04 0.5024192810058594 0.5156547546386718 0.007733154296875 0.012339401245117187 0.04 16842 8022 19 39 14 12 0 0 0 0 0 0 251.6710347854035 0.33500003196735756
4 -12.069767441860465 -0.42 6553.202187039003 0.04 0.5022262573242188 0.5153728485107422 0.007544326782226563 0.012156295776367187 0.04 16846 8023 18 39 14 12 0 0 0 0 0 0 251.6710347854035 0.380000042623143
#C Acquisition ended at Thu Jul  6 20:21:52 2023


df = pd.read_csv('../pythonzzyy/aa.dat', engine = 'python', delim_whitespace = True, header = None)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the lines starting with a `#` character are comments, you can use:

```
df = pd.read_csv(<file_path>, delim_whitespace = True, comment='#')
```

Other useful options for dealing with lines in your CSV that do not contain data are `on_bad_lines` and `skiprows` / `skipfooter`.

Also refer to the [documentation of `pandas.read_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).